# Why is there an error? kotlin (unresolved reference)

Tags: kotlin

I have question

android studio kotlin

unresolved reference : .append

What is the solution?

thank you

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var a: String = ""
    var list = mutableListOf<String>()
    var b: Long = 0L
    var c: Long = 1L

    var d: Double = 1.0
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        num1.setOnClickListener {
            all_result.setText(all_result.getText().append("1"))
            a = all_result.getText().toString()        
}        
}    
}
```

Comment: Did you check the type of what's returned from `all_result.getText()`? ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `all_result` in your case is `EditText`. In this case `getText()` returns `Editable`, but not `String` or `StringBuilder`. So, you should write something like this: `"${all_result.getText().toString()}1"` to concatenate existing string in `EditText` with '1'